Best practice when backing up up persistent container data in Podman
I'm using Vaultwarden to store passwords and other sensitive data. Vaultwarden runs in a container, where the SQLite database is hosted on a volume mapped to the host. The configuration is stored in a Quadlet file.
Obviously, this data is important to me, so I want to make a backup. I'm looking at Duplicati to do the job. I prefer to have Duplicati also running in a container.
How should I present the volume to Duplicati? Should I create a pod and have both containers in the same pod, or should I create two separate containers and map the volume twice? What are the best practices in this scenario?

It Depends on your use case,
Case [1]:
If you need simplified management, lower latency & low network overhead then you can go for shared volume within a pod.
Case [2]:
If you prefer flexiblility, Isolation & Independent scaling then go for separate containers with same volume mounted.
But make sure you limit the access of Backup Container to the volume as: Read Only
Example Kubernetes Pod Config:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: xyz
spec:
  containers:
  - name: vaultwarden
    image: xyz
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/vw-data
      name: vaultwarden-data
      readOnly: false
  - name: backup-container
    image: duplicati
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /opt/vw-data
      name: vaultwarden-data
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: vaultwarden-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: my-pvc

And, If you are using separate docker containers then, add :ro to the end of path of volume mounted inside the container:
docker run -d --name backup-container -v /opt/vw-data:/path/in/container:ro backupvw

